# Android Camera is not responding (Fail to connect to camera service)

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I know there are lots of questions like this. However, nothing worked out for me. I am learning android through a self- learning guide. My task is to implement a camera service using Camera class. I know that Camera is deprecated. However, I am planning to make it run using the Camera class. I am getting failed to connect to camera service error. I am not even getting a camera preview. When I run the camera, all I get is a black screen and a click button that I made to click the picture. However, running it the second time freezes my mobile and I have to pull out and put in the battery to work again. So far, I have put every permission that camera class requires
Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"></uses-feature>
    <application>....</application>
```

I am making sure that camera is released at all the required places. I learned that we get this error when we do not release camera properly. 
My onPause() Method

```
   @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(camera!=null)
        {
            camera.release();
            camera=null;
        }
}
```

My onResume method

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    {
        camera.open(0);

    }
    else {
        camera.open();

    }
```

My surfaceDestroyed method

```
 @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if(camera!=null)
                {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    camera.release();
                    camera=null;
                }
            }
```

My surfaceCreated method

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if(camera!=null)
            {
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR SETTING UP PREVIEW", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

My console output:

```
Process: course.examples.criminalintent, PID: 12954
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {course.examples.criminalintent/course.examples.criminalintent.CrimeCameraActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

After some debugging, I found that my camera is null throughout the time. This explains why I cannot see camera preview on screen. However, I don't understand why it freezes my mobile and How should I make it work properly? Please explain in detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The first thing that was wrong with my onResume() method is that it was not surrounded in a try catch block. Moreover, I replaced constants like 0 with constants like (Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT).

Secondly, I was getting parameter failed error. I removed that error by removing setPreviewFormat(format) statement.

Here are the changes that I made:

Updated onResume() method

```
try {
                releaseCameraAndPreview();
                if (Id == 0) {
                    camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                }
                else {
                    camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```